# Foreign key fails on deletion because Hibernate doesn't remove association first

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, constraints, sql-delete

I have a problem with constraint fail when I cascade-delete entity which references another entity.

I'm using *Hibernate* as my JPA Provider.

### Domain model:

[image: ERD]

- Every `Zone` can have more `Actions`, but `Actions` are not shared between `Zones` (*OneToMany*).
- `TeleportAction` (one possible kind of `Action`) contains a set of `Zones` as targets. Every `TeleportAction` can have more `Zones` as targets and `Zones` and they can be used by multiple `TeleportActions` (*ManyToMany*).

### How deletion works

1. I call `ZoneManager.deleteZone(zone)`

   1. ZoneManager first loops through all `Zones` and their `TeleportActions` and removes deleted `Zone` from their targets.
   2. After that ZoneManager removes given `Zone` from it's list of `Zones`
2. Then I delete `Zone` from DB with *Hibernate* via `session.delete(zone)`. This operation propagates to `Actions`.
3. List item

First `ZoneManager.deleteZone(zone)` is called, which works like this:

```java
public void deleteZone(Zone removedZone) {

    // Remove this zone from all TeleportActions
    for (Zone zone : zones) {
        for (Action action : zone.getActions()) {
            if (action instanceof TeleportAction) {
                ((TeleportAction)action).removeTarget(removedZone);
            }
        }
    }

    // Finally remove zone
    zones.remove(removedZone);
}
```

then caller removes `Zone` from DB. I want Hibernate to automatically acknowledge that I've removed this `Zone` from `Action` targets.

```java
session.delete(removedZone);
```

### Error which I get

```
Hibernate: /* delete cz.iwitrag.greencore.gameplay.zones.Zone */ delete from gcore_Zone where id=?
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`309145_mysql_db`.`gcore_tpaction_targetzones`, CONSTRAINT `FK4rvpdg8xjyt6lk5281jbi78c5` FOREIGN KEY (`targetZone_id`) REFERENCES `gcore_Zone` (`id`))
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
```

This error is caused because when I delete `Zone`, it is still target of some `TeleportActions`.

Even though I deleted this `Zone` from `TeleportAction's` targets in business code before calling `session.delete(zone)`, *Hibernate* doesn't acknowledge it and doesn't remove this `Zone` from *ManyToMany* association.

### Entities

`Zone`, which has List of `Actions`

```java
@Entity
public class Zone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "list_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "zone_id")
    private List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

`Action`, which is superclass of `TeleportAction`

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "actionType")
public abstract class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
...
}
```

`TeleportAction`, which contains Set of `Zones` as teleport targets.
Please note that this relationship is different from `Zone->Action` relationship.

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("tp")
public class TeleportAction extends Action {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "tpaction_targetzones", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tpAction_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="targetZone_id"))
    private Set<Zone> targets = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

### Question

How can I force *Hibernate* to **automatically** delete removed `Zone` from table `tpaction_targetzones` before it actually deletes `Zone` from database to avoid foreign key constraint error?

Comment: Can you paste `ZoneManager` class? I would like to see the code, that deletes the entities (not only the description)

Comment: @Andronicus ZoneManager is not responsible for entity deletion (from DB), it is responsible for managing list of Zones in business code. Database stuff is done outside.
I will update question with actual code.

Comment: One more question - is there anything keeping you from making relationship `Zone` - `TeleportAction` bidirectional?

Comment: Yes, it would make managing of this entity more difficult, because TeleportAction targets are changed frequently in the code and it just doesn't make sense in this case. Zone does not need to know that it's being target of someone.